# Set cookie for removed element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am having a element with a X (close) icon in the top right corner.
When clicking that close icon I am hiding the element with some jQuery.
When I am on a new page in the same session the element comes back again. I want to set a cookie for hiding the element after the user clicked the close icon in the session. I found this to set a cookie but what needs to be inside?:

This is my code for the element

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//Add close icon in top right corner of element
jQuery("<a class='verwijderen_messenger' href='#'></a>").insertBefore("a#fbmsg-icon");

jQuery("a.verwijderen_messenger").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //Hide element
        jQuery("a#fbmsg-icon").css("display", "none");
        jQuery("a.verwijderen_messenger").css("display", "none");
        //
        sessionStorage.setItem("messenger", "hidden");
});

  if (sessionStorage.getItem("messenger") == "hidden") {
            jQuery("a.verwijderen_messenger").remove();
            jQuery("a#fbmsg-icon").remove();
  } 
  else {}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `localStorage.setItem(key,value)` to set a variable into the local browser and `localStorage.getItem(key)` to get.

In your example it would be: `localStorage.setItem(messenger, 'hidden')` and then get the variable in the next window by

```
if(localStorage.getItem(messenger)=='hidden') {
    hideDiv();
} else {
    showDiv();
}
```

Comment: Edited my code, would be something like this in my `functions.php` file?

Comment: That's javascript, not php... you would need a `functions.js`

Comment: I know but I write js in my functions.php too

Comment: It might be confusing to find your scripts later, but it works as well... i'd rather separate the php functions from the js ones...

Comment: Hi, I edited my code according to your answer. It is working fine now!

Comment: Glad i could help, thats my first answer in stack overflow... ^^

Comment: Basically I meant Guillaume Racicot with 'your' haha

Comment: he indented/beautified my code... im new here, he helped me

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, haven't seen that ;) thanks instead!!

Answer (score 0):

Here are three functions to create, call and erase cookies. But i would suggest looking into localstorage as they don't expire like a cookie after a set period

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```